# Add active class to current element with JS (not Jquery)

Tags: javascript, dom

What would be the best way to add the active class to an "active/current" element with PLAIN JavaScript?

With jQuery you would use the typical:

```
$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

But with JavaScript (not vanilla JS, jQuery, etc)??

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meEf4/2065/

Comment: querySelectorAll loops addEventListener, classList

Comment: can you show me? thanks! with a fiddle?=)

Comment: @AngieR check my answer, it is exactly what you need

Comment: "vanilla JS" is the same as "plain JavaScript".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the element that has `active` class. Since there will be only one `<a>` with `active` class so you can directly access the `<a>`  Now replace that `active` class will no text. Finally, add the `active` class to the clicked `<a>` element.

First attach a click handler to all the `<a>` tags:

```
const navAnchor = document.querySelectorAll('a');

navAnchor.forEach(anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', addActive);
})
```

Now, create a function `addActive` as below:

```
function addActive(e) {
  const current = document.querySelector('.active');
  current.className = current.className.replace("active", "");
  e.target.className += "active";
```

}

Comment: But now you're using jQuery.. except for the methods

Comment: Ok, i have edited my answer. Check now